# Octave GUI unable to save plot

Tags: octave

I am currently using GUI version octave 3.8.1. When i try to save a plot using the command.

print -deps myplot.eps

i get the following error

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

I understand that its because of the white space in the path 'Program Files" that causing the problem but am not sure how to fix it.

I tried to add the path using add path command. It does not help either. Can some let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the Octave MXE 3.8.1-5 from http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/ and install to a directory without whitespace.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, it even supports 64-bits indexes!

Comment: Had the exact same problem as OP, and this binary fixed my problem (I also moved my app to a non whitespace path). Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem I learned that three packages for graphs and plotting are available with my Octave 4.0.3 installation. Only one seems to save graphics to a file properly. Use the following command to select it:

graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot")

The "default" pre-selected toolkit apparently doesn't work for me, but the gnuplot does !?!

Read more about the [graphics_toolkit options](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Introduction-to-Plotting.html).